# updateViewConstraints called when creating constraints in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, autolayout

Currently I'm experiencing a strange behavior. I removed the auto resizing mask from a view for `viewForHeaderInSection`. When I'm doing this the app crashes because I tried to remove a constraint which is nil.

I'm creating the concerned constraints in `viewDidLoad` in my parent controller. In debug mode I found out that when the system tries to create a constraint where my child view controller is involved (which has the removed auto resizing mask from the section header view) it directly jumps to `updateViewConstraints`. Of course the constraints are nil because the weren't created yet.

- If I add again the auto resizing mask the app works, but I can't do what I'm trying to do (to layout my views correctly).
- If I create my constraints in `updateViewConstraints` the app also works.

I don't understand why this is happening. On a similar view controller it is working without problems. Sometimes I think auto layout is more a pain than a gain. On a server error an alert was displayed. Here the view could be correctly loaded. Seems that this is a kind of timing problem.

I want to know why this is happening and how should I proceed in future that such an error doesn't happen anymore. Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit:**

Don't know if it helps but if I call `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded` on the view of my child view controller in `viewDidLoad` of my parent then also the app crashes.

**Edit 2:**

Seems that it occurs when I add multiple views with constraints on different places to my view controller. For my table I add an empty message if there are currently no entries. If I don't add the label as subview to my table everything works fine.

So when I'm allowed to add my constraints? Currently I add them right after the view was added as subview. For the empty message it is in `viewDidLoad` and for the section header it is `viewForHeaderInSection`. Do I have to use something like `setNeedsLayout`?

**Edit 3:**

Adding a subview to the table view isn't a good idea at all (especially when using auto layout). For now I'm using the background view, but that's not the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm confused by the question. In the first paragraph, you say you are trying to remove an autoresizing mask... If you don't want the mask, why add it in the first place? Then you say the app crashes because you tried to remove a missing constraint... Why are you trying to remove a constraint that doesn't exist?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The auto resizing mask is enabled by default. I have to disable it when I want to use auto layout (`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is set to `NO`). The constraint doesn't exist because he do not finish creating it in `viewDidLoad`. When he wants to create it, he jumps right to `updateViewConstraints` instead of creating my constraints ...

Comment: I'm sorry, but no, autoresizing masks are not enabled by default. If you create a UIView programmatically, it will have no autoresizing masks set, if you create a view in the xib/storyboard file, and are using constraints in it, you can't access autoresizing masks to turn them on.

Comment: I'm creating my views programmatically :-) Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to change the value of `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` unless you actually have set the `autoresizingMask` to something other than 0. If you are using constraints, the solution is to completely ignore `autoresizingMask` and `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`.

Comment: I don't have set a value for the `autoresizingMask`. But if I don't set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` I get an auto layout error (*Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints*). Here I can see that an constraint from the auto resizing mask has been applied (in my case it says that the header has a height of 0). Than it brakes one of my constraints and shows the view correctly, but in the console the auto layout error is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Now I got the same problem again. My workaround didn't worked:

```
// on iOS 7 this would bring "Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UITableView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super." and the app crashes
// on iOS 8 this is needed, otherwise "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints."
// bug?
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (8, 0)) {
    sectionHeader.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
}
```

What I've found out so far is that it has to do with the **headerview** and the **empty message** (view). When both are used I get this problem. Either the app crashes or I get

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

depending if I have the autoresizing mask turned off or not. Interestingly, only iOS 8 made this problem with my workaround. A solution would be to set a boolean variable in `viewDidLoad` if the constraints have been set up and check for this in `updateViewConstraints`. But I wanted to know the real cause for this and not using a workaround for a workaround ...

Every time I retrieve new data for my table I checked if the number of records is zero or not. If they were zero I showed my empty message. The problem seems to be caused by the `reloadData`, which I called before this check. Than `UITableViewHeaderFooterContentView` got a height of zero from the `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint`. Restructuring my code to this variant

```
if (myList.Count == 0) {
    this.TableView.BackgroundView = emptyMessage;
    this.TableView.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
} else {
    this.TableView.BackgroundView = null;

    this.TableView.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine;
    if (emptyMessage != null) {
        emptyMessage.RemoveFromSuperview ();
    }
}
// call this afterwards!
TableView.ReloadData();
```

seems to solve my issue.